# Initializer list vs. vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initialization, initializer-list

In C++11, one can use initializer lists to initialize parameters in functions. What is the purpose of it? Can't the same be done with const vectors? What is the difference of the two programs below?

Using an initializer list:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int sumL(initializer_list<int> l){
    int sum = 0;
    for (const auto i: l){
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){

    cout << sumL({1, 2, 3}) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Using a const vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int sumV(const vector<int> l){
    int sum = 0;
    for (const auto i: l){
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){

    cout << sumV({1, 2, 3}) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second code requires more than needed (and the vector is constructed withe an initializer_list, too)

Comment: Offtopic: note that you make a copy of the vector, i.e., you didn't use a reference &. The same holds in the for loop, now it is just an int but with larger objects the reference will avoid that you copy each object in the vector.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The common use of `std::initializer_list` is as argument to constructors of container (and similar) classes, allowing convenient initialisation of those containers from a few objects of the same type.
Of course, you can use `std::initializer_list` otherwise and then use the same `{}` syntax.

Since a  `std::initializer_list` has a fixed size, it doesn't require dynamic allocation and hence can be efficiently implemented. A `std::vector`, on the other hand, requires dynamic memory allocation. Even in your simple example it is unlikely that the compiler will optimize this overhead away (avoid the intermediary `std::vector` and its dynamic memory allocation). Other than that, there is no difference in the outcome of your programs (though you should take a `const std::vector<int>&` argument to avoid a copy and its associated dynamic memory allocation).

Answer (score 12):

`initializer_list` uses optimal storage location and prevents unnecessary calls, it's designed to be lightweight, while with `vector` there's a heap allocation and there may be more copies/moves made.

Answer (score 7):

The semantics of the two are quite different. The `initializer_list` has pointer semantics while the `vector` has value semantics.

In your first example, the compiler will generate code similar to the following:

```
int const __temp_array[3] = {1, 2, 3};
cout << sumL(std::initializer_list<int>(__temp_array, __temp_array + 3)) << "\n";
```

This is explained in *[dcl.init.list]/5*. As you can see, within `sumL` you have access to `const` pointers to the elements of the *braced-init-list*, this means you have no other option but to copy the elements out of the list.

In case of `sumV` you could've `std::moved` the elements from the `vector` if needed (assuming the parameter type is not `const`).

Similarly, copying the `initializer_list` performs shallow copies, i.e. only the pointers will be copied, while copying the `vector`, of course, means the elements will be copied.

In your example, none of the points above really make any difference, other than constructing the `vector` will require dynamic memory allocation, while constructing the `initializer_list` will not.

Comment: Thank you for details. Please clarify for me one thing. Am i right if say `initializer_list<object> il1 = {...};` stores objects inside container (or somewhere, on stack?), and then its copy `initializer_list<object> il2 = il1;` stores links to objects so every copy of that `il`s will share the same objects?

Comment: the answer is yes. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17ec0b32e0d57a77

Answer (score 7):

initalizer_list is not a generalized container like std::vector.  It's primary purpose is object initialization.  If the low overheard and no heap allocation is attractive to you I'd suggest looking at std::array.  It a fixed sized stack allocated array that has all the conveniences of a STL container, which is essentially a thin wrapper on top of a c-array.

Answer (score 0):

**Initializer lists**

A lightweight array-like container of elements created using a "braced list" syntax. For example, { 1, 2, 3 } creates a sequences of integers, that has type std::initializer_list. Useful as a replacement to passing a vector of objects to a function.

```
  int sum(const std::initializer_list<int>& list) {
  int total = 0;
  for (auto& e : list) {
    total += e;
  }

  return total;
}

auto list = {1, 2, 3};
sum(list); // == 6
sum({1, 2, 3}); // == 6
sum({}); // == 0
```

However, in your case if you will do it the way you are doing compiler likely to optimize it the same way as you can see the vector function implementation mentioned below.

```
template <class T>
struct S {
    std::vector<T> v;
    S(std::initializer_list<T> l) : v(l) {
         std::cout << "constructed with a " << l.size() << "-element list\n";
    }
    void append(std::initializer_list<T> l) {
        v.insert(v.end(), l.begin(), l.end());
    }
    std::pair<const T*, std::size_t> c_arr() const {
        return {&v[0], v.size()};  // copy list-initialization in return statement
                                   // this is NOT a use of std::initializer_list
    }
};
```