# Using std::initializer_list[] as const list of lists of varying length

Tags: c++, c++11, nested-lists, initializer-list, compile-time-constant

I need a static const **list of lists of varying length** (of `QPointF` from Qt) that I directly initialize in my code (see below), and which is only used read-only later on.

I first used `const std::vector<QPointF>[]` for that, but then it ocured to me that I could just use `const std::initializer_list<QPointF>[]` instead (is the `const` even necessary?).

```cpp
static const std::initializer_list<QPointF> points[6] = {
        { { 0.50f, 0.50f } },
        { { 0.25f, 0.25f }, { 0.75f, 0.75f } },
        { { 0.25f, 0.25f }, { 0.50f, 0.50f }, { 0.75f, 0.75f } },
        { { 0.25f, 0.25f }, { 0.75f, 0.75f }, { 0.25f, 0.75f }, { 0.75f, 0.25f } },
        { { 0.25f, 0.25f }, { 0.75f, 0.75f }, { 0.50f, 0.50f }, { 0.25f, 0.75f }, { 0.75f, 0.25f } },
        { { 0.25f, 0.25f }, { 0.75f, 0.75f }, { 0.25f, 0.50f }, { 0.75f, 0.50f }, { 0.25f, 0.75f }, { 0.75f, 0.25f } },
    };
```

Is this a valid use of `std::initializer_list`? It looks like a hack to me, probably because the name of `std::iniatilizer_list` suggests a certain use. Answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27753420/7920139) post also mention that initializer lists are intended to be used for, well, initialization of e.g. containers.

I also considered `const std::array<...>[]`, but then all the inner lists have to be of the same length.

If `std::initializer_list` is not the right choice here, then how to do this correctly. The alternative `std::vector` does not feel right because of the heap allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing your compiler output can help you with this decision. `std::initializer_list<>` is [just a thin wrapper around an array of objects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

If you really need static constant data, `std::initializer_list<>[]` is perfectly valid (as long as you don't mind using its accessing syntax instead of subscript operators like you would find on `std::array<>` or `std::vector<>`). Clang 8 lowers each `initializer_list` in the array to its own fixed-length array of `QPointF` structs. It then fills another array with references to the `QPointF` arrays it created:

```
// pseudo-C++ from Clang's generated output

QPointF RT1[1] = { { 0.50f, 0.50f } };
QPointF RT2[2] = { { 0.25f, 0.25f }, { 0.75f, 0.75f } };
QPointF RT3[3] = { { 0.25f, 0.25f }, { 0.50f, 0.50f }, { 0.75f, 0.75f } };
QPointF RT4[4] = { { 0.25f, 0.25f }, { 0.75f, 0.75f }, { 0.25f, 0.75f }, { 0.75f, 0.25f } };
QPointF RT5[5] = { { 0.25f, 0.25f }, { 0.75f, 0.75f }, { 0.50f, 0.50f }, { 0.25f, 0.75f }, { 0.75f, 0.25f } };
QPointF RT6[6] = { { 0.25f, 0.25f }, { 0.75f, 0.75f }, { 0.25f, 0.50f }, { 0.75f, 0.50f }, { 0.25f, 0.75f }, { 0.75f, 0.25f } };

// Reference array:
QPointF* points[6] = { RT1, RT2, RT3, RT4, RT5, RT6 };
```

Accessing individual values from the list

```
(points[5].begin() + 3)->y
```

is lowered to *essentially* the equivalent of

```
points[5][3].y
// alternatively:
(*(*(points + 5) + 3)).y
// which is actually:
(*(RT5 + 3)).y
```

(Implementations of `std::initializer_list<>::begin()` can differ.)

So if you don't mind hidden dereferences or different syntax styles, this is fine. (Although you would have dereferenecs occuring with arrays or vectors, too.)

Try it with different optimization levels and see the results: https://godbolt.org/z/Vwjbp2

Answer (score 0):

The standard says

> An object of type initializer_list provides access to an array of objects of type const E.

It does not suggests that such objects are to be used exclusively as temporaries for initialising other objects, though this is without a doubt the primary intended use. The standard actually provides an example of it being correctly used as a variable.

So I cannot see anything wrong with what you have done.